# Trivial answer converted in comment

Tags: support

I asked a question on unix.stackexchange [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174558/use-only-one-wireless-card-to-connect-to-wifi-network-and-share-internet-through)

Nobody answered, but luckily I found solution on askubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap)

I thought to answer my question myself by giving the link, so that other users can find solution to their similar problem.

but whenever I type the answer it gets converted to comment giving me this: *answer* + `Trivial answer converted in comment`

answer:

```
this helped me, found it on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,  we don't like link only answers.  Thanks for taking the time to post an answer but please explain the solution you found instead of just linking to it. That way the information is *here* and not on another web page.

Since it comes from another SE site,  you can just copy the relevant parts directly into your answer and link back to the original.